# Toggling accordion classes use angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have created a custom Angular accordion menu. I have the basics working the menus open and close. One issue i am having when I click on toggle menu two i want the added class on toggle menu one to be removed. [Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/401xj3rk/20/)

Below is a snippet of code.

```
<div class="frq-accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <!-- PANEL STARTS HERE-->
    <div ng-click="frqToggle('hiddenToggleOne')" class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-title">
        <span>Some text goes here!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- PANEL HEADING ENDS HERE -->
    <div id="collapseOne" ng-class="{isHidden: hiddenToggleOne}" class="panel-collapse">
      <p>Hidden menu is open</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- PANEL ENDS HERE -->
</div>
<!-- FRQ ACCORDION CONTAINER ENDS HERE -->

<div class="frq-accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <!-- PANEL STARTS HERE-->
    <div ng-click="frqToggle('hiddenToggleTwo')" class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-title">
        <span>Some text goes here!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- PANEL HEADING ENDS HERE -->
    <div id="collapseTwo" ng-class="{isHidden: hiddenToggleTwo}" class="panel-collapse">
      <p>Hidden menu is open</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- PANEL ENDS HERE -->
</div>
<!-- FRQ ACCORDION CONTAINER ENDS HERE -->

<div class="frq-accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <!-- PANEL STARTS HERE-->
    <div ng-click="frqToggle('hiddenToggleThree')" class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-title">
        <span>Some text goes here!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- PANEL HEADING ENDS HERE -->
    <div id="collapseThree" ng-class="{isHidden: hiddenToggleThree}" class="panel-collapse">
      <p>Hidden menu is open</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- PANEL ENDS HERE -->
</div>
```

ANGULAR

```
  $scope.hiddenToggleOne = true;
$scope.hiddenToggleTwo = false;
$scope.hiddenToggleThree = false;
$scope.hiddenToggleFour = false;
$scope.hiddenToggleFive = false;

$scope.frqToggle = function(toggleElem) {
  $scope[toggleElem] = !$scope[toggleElem];
}
```

Comment: The fiddle is not working. I dont think you have added the external resources for your JS files

Answer (score 0):

Reset every boolean to 'false' before you toggle.

```
$scope.frqToggle = function(toggleElem) {
  resetAllToFalse();
  $scope[toggleElem] = !$scope[toggleElem];
};

var resetAllToFalse = function(){
  $scope.hiddenToggleOne = false;
  $scope.hiddenToggleTwo = false;
  $scope.hiddenToggleThree = false;
  $scope.hiddenToggleFour = false;
  $scope.hiddenToggleFive = false;
};
```

or, you may try a different approach as such,

In the controller, add the below code

```
$scope.activeTab = 1;

$scope.changeActiveTabTo = function(tabIndex){
  $scope.activeTab = tabIndex;
}
```

and replace your html by the below pasted

```
<div class="frq-accordion">   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <!-- PANEL STARTS HERE-->
    <div ng-click="changeActiveTabTo(1)” class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-title">
        <span>Some text goes here!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- PANEL HEADING ENDS HERE -->
    <div id="collapseOne" ng-show=“activeTab == 1” class="panel-collapse">
      <p>Hidden menu is open</p>
    </div>   </div>   <!-- PANEL ENDS HERE --> </div> <!-- FRQ ACCORDION CONTAINER ENDS HERE -->

<div class="frq-accordion">   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <!-- PANEL STARTS HERE-->
    <div ng-click="changeActiveTabTo(2)” class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-title">
        <span>Some text goes here!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- PANEL HEADING ENDS HERE -->
    <div id="collapseTwo" ng-show=“activeTab == 2”  class="panel-collapse">
      <p>Hidden menu is open</p>
    </div>   </div>   <!-- PANEL ENDS HERE --> </div> <!-- FRQ ACCORDION CONTAINER ENDS HERE -->

<div class="frq-accordion">   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <!-- PANEL STARTS HERE-->
    <div ng-click="changeActiveTabTo(3)” class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-title">
        <span>Some text goes here!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- PANEL HEADING ENDS HERE -->
    <div id="collapseThree" ng-show=“activeTab == 3”  class="panel-collapse">
      <p>Hidden menu is open</p>
    </div>   </div>   <!-- PANEL ENDS HERE --> </div>
```

Comment: Can you reformat the last bit of your answer please, its hard to read

Comment: Replace all of frqToggle(hiddenToggle*) with changeActiveTabTo(1) (integer based on the tab) function. And instead of ng-class="{isHidden: hiddenToggleThree}", you can write ng-show="activeTab == 1" (again that integer based on the tab)

Comment: In the html that you provided, 
replace the functions frqToggle() by changeActiveTabTo(tabIndex). ( tabIndex being 1/2/3/4/5 based on the tab)

And replace 
 ng-class="{isHidden: hiddenToggleThree}"  by 
ng-show="activeTab == tabIndex" (tabIndex being integer 1/2/3/4/5 based on the tab)

Comment: Either i've miss understood what you've wrote, or it doesn't work

Comment: I'll like to see a jsfiddle example. I have tried this solution and it doesn't work